# Why Rails ActiveRecord last method orders by id whereas first does not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, activerecord

According to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), ActiveRecord `first` generates the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 1
```

whereas ActiveRecord `last` generates the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY clients.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

The behavior on `first` is not correct, according to my opinion, whereas on `last` it is. If you do not specify the ordering, simple SELECT returns in arbitrary or unpredictable order. Hence, `first` does not guarrantee to return the same record always (if not the record with minimum id).

Does anybody have a clue, why does Rails ActiveRecord work like that?

Thanks in advance
Panayotis

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. I believe `first` always returns the record with minimum id. In which scenario it would behave differently ?

Comment: @sub_stantial How do you know/believe that ```SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 1``` returns the record with minimum id? Is it somewhere documented? According to [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_2094997_sort-mysql-query-using-order.html) order is arbitrary and non-deterministic. Also in [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sorting-rows.html) the first  phrase says that results are returned in no particular order, unless you apply order by. Please provide any reference that proves your statement and I will accept this.

Comment: I just wanted `first` to return the first result that was returned by the query (it's supposed to be an alias for `[0]`). But instead, it changes my `GROUP BY` query to require the `id` column, which I deliberately left out using `.select` (because IDs are unique, so there wouldn't be any grouping!). So `.first` now behaves "correctly", but the "correct" behavior is actually pretty bad behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't get any answer on this post, I tried to find the answer from other people on other forums. I believe that either ActiveRecord (or mysql gem) has a bug. Rick James says that if we want to get the minimum id, we should use order by with limit. [Here is his answer](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,530328,530514#msg-530514):

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,530328,530514#msg-530514

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a de jure, but a de facto rule. Most DB's returns the content of the table in order of creation (so in order of their id's) in case of no ordering was specified. It just works.

Comment: Order of creation is *not* the same as the order of the ids; there are id generation schemes besides things like auto_increment, like UUIDs.

Comment: I think the default ID generation in rails is based on auto increment. You can use UUID if you disable the default id generation, and manually set the UUID up. It worths a try to see what rails `.first` and `.last` generate on a table using UUID and no default ID.